# Why nuke the "working-holiday" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We got our first working holiday program question the other day so I created a tag for this huge topic but now it's been deleted again. Did I miss the reason? I work in the hospitality business when I'm not travelling and over 50% of our guests are on working holiday visas from English, Ireland, Europe, Japan, Korea, Chile, and now finally a few Americans too.

Is it considered not travel related or too insignificant a topic to get many more questions or some other reason?

(**EDIT** The original question wording included the word "visa" which I hadn't intended to be there.)

Answer (score 4):

(Answer rather than comment so I can use more space and formatting)

I hadn't heard of the American sense of "working holiday". Wikipedia treats "working holiday" as redirect to "working holiday visa" but Wikipedia has a system for handling ambiguity.

Getting your visa is only one small aspect of a working holiday. The trip will typically last 6 to 12 months. There could be lots of questions particular to working holidays which are not questions about the visa. We might have to wait and see. We could overload the tag with the "-visa" suffix to specifically cover it all though and say so in the tagwiki.

Saying the US doesn't participate in the program is one of those "100% true but 100% useless" answers (-: Though the US does not offer such visas, some countries (including Australia) offer them to US citizens. So US citizens do participate in the scheme. I believe there are even some special rules for US citizens to get working holiday visas since due to the non-reciprocal arrangement they are a bit special.

Your point of "tag is redundant if text appears in question" does not seem to be applied anywhere on SE!

I think the prediction of a "limited life expectancy" of working holiday related questions is astonishing.

All topics start with one question, should we not create new tags until at least two questions for a topic are asked?

Comment: Actually it seems a bit blurrier WRT the US situation. It could be that there may be a particular program with lots of countries involved specifically called "Working Holiday" and also a casual use of the term "working holiday" which people also use for the arrangements with the US. I haven't untangled it all yet but I had only been aware of the casual use which includes the US.

Comment: "In general, a tag that is only applied to a single question is a tag with a limited life expectancy. The whole point of tagging is categorization, and a category with only a single member isn't helpful."

Comment: So putting the official Working Holiday Visa and the similar programs that everyone calls working holidays under one tag would be a point of confusion but putting all kinds of accommodation from hostels to hotels would not?

Comment: Working holidays are very common in Europe, particularly with woofing, which is international, and horse-riding.

Answer (score 1):

[working-holiday](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working-holiday) exists and has been applied to [41 open questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bworking-holiday%5D+closed%3A0), so seems likely to remain around for the indefinite future.